# BlackBerry - Extract data from 3rd nesting level of xml

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

```
<autos>
    <cars>
      <car>
        <type>Toyota</type>
        <year>1999</year>
      </car>
      <car>
        <type>Honda</type>
        <year>2010</year>
      </car>
    </cars>
</autos>
```

i want to extract car object from the above code whats the possible way. can i have the sample code or any example

thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post followups to your question as answers. Only actual answers should be posted as answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SAX parser here.  Check element name, if its car, create instance of car object if its type or year, take characters and set properties of car object... etc

See similar approach:  [SO - BlackBerry/J2ME - SAX parse collection of objects with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451356/blackberry-j2me-sax-parse-collection-of-objects-with-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Here is the sample xml file

```
<cars>

  <car>

    <type>Toyota</type>

    <year>1990</year>

  </car>

  <car>

    <type>Honda</type>

    <year>1998</year>
  </car>
```