# How to parse XML from within a mobile?

Tags: java, xml, blackberry

I've looked into XOM but it seems that it doesn't work on mobile phones (blackberry).

How can I parse XML to get information out of it using Java on the Blackberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options:

[Parse XML file on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757990/blackberry-how-to-parse-xml-file)

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/xml/jaxp/package-tree.html

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry has its own XML-Parser, see here:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/xml/jaxp/XMLParser.html