# How to parse XML in Blackberry?

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse XML file on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757990/parse-xml-file-on-blackberry)

Can anyone tell me how to parse this xml...
I am new to blackberry app development. I don't know how to parse xml.

```
<Main tag>
    <subtagfirst>data</subtagfirst>
    <subtagsec>data1</subtagsec>
    <subtagthird>data1</subtagthird> 
    <Main sub tag>
        <Main sub tag 1>
        <sub tag1>
            <id>1</id>
            <name> abc</name>
        </sub tag1>
        <sub tag2>
            <data1>xyz</data1>
            <data2>pqr</data2>
        </sub tag2>
        </Main sub tag 1>
    </Main sub tag>
</Main tag>
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for rply but i cant understand pls explain me.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [KXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/) and parse the XML. Look at this article, [KXML
  parsing.](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11773)

**OR**

- Use SAX Parser. Look at this article, [How to use the XML Parser?](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800599/How_To_-_Use_the_XML_Parser.html?nodeid=820554&vernum=0)