# Parsing XML in BlackBerry java plug-in

Tags: xml-parsing, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to parse xml file present on my computer into a project.I m using blackberry eclipse java plug-in environment.Please tell me the whole procedure, as i m a beginner.........thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at The demo **XML DEMO** comes with Blackberry eclipse plugin for blackberry. Copy your `XML file` in the **res** folder in the blackberry project. And You can use `SAX Parser` or `DOM Parser` to parse the XML file.

Comment: have you seen the demo how it is parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757990/parse-xml-file-on-blackberry see this link