# Creating interface between a java class & a complete built project

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a requirement where, I need to give the user only one editable java class where he can make changes in the program such as changing username, changing phone number. The moment he saves the data, the built program should be able to reproduce the changes.

I am doing this project for BlackBerry.

I want to know, is there any way in which I can link a class with external project? I am developing the project using Eclipse. I don't know how the user will make changes and save. I know it's a little weird but generally speaking, I want to link two different applications using some middle interface. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: why you want to give user a class? give him a file may be text one.

Comment: Alright I am giving him a .txt file to edit. Then when he saves the file, how will that reflect in the project that is already built?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a simple case of "You think you know what you want but you really don't" :)

Please explain what it is you want to achieve between your two apps and how they interact and we will provide you with a much better solution than asking a user to modify java files.

**UPDATE AFTER OP COMMENT :**

You need to look at XML or JSON. These are ways to format data so that it is easy to write/produce/transfert/parse.

Parsing XML on Blackberry
[Parse XML file on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757990/parse-xml-file-on-blackberry)

Comment: Basically I am doing a graph application for business use. Suppose you are a businessman who wants to see a graph of your sales,you will download my app and give input of certain nos.The input should not be manually entered. It should be fetched from server(JSON,XML,DB..) My app should reproduce it in the form of graph. Right now I have hardcoded the input. I want to make it user friendly where no matter who edits it, the graph should be created to suit their needs.How do I do it

Comment: Edited my answer to give you directions.

Comment: Thanks but I have already done this in Android. I am working on BlackBerry. Anyways I will keep you updated. Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, updated my post again.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a java project you get a jar file. If you include that jar file into the classpath, all of its contents will be available to your code (with necessary import statements).