# Parsing XML webservice in black berry

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I need to parse below xml file in black berry

```
<Vehicles> 
    <Car> 
        <ID>000001</ID> 
        <Make>Audi</Make> 
    </Car> 
    <Car> 
        <ID>000002</ID> 
        <Make>Buick</Make> 
    </Car> 
    <Car> 
        <ID>000015</ID> 
        <Make>Chevrolet</Make> 
    </Car> 
    <Car> 
        <ID>000003</ID> 
        <Make>Chrysler</Make> 
    </Car>  
</Vehicles>
```

Can any one pleae tell me how to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look into the following posts in stackoverflow.com

[Parse XML file on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757990/parse-xml-file-on-blackberry)

[BlackBerry/J2ME - SAX parse collection of objects with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451356/blackberry-j2me-sax-parse-collection-of-objects-with-attributes)

Note: Please search in stackoverflow.com before post an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point check the "xmldemo" sample app. It is a part of the BB SDK placed on your PC. XMLDemoScreen has an example of a DOM-parser implementaion.